# Shiny: Apply code to input file

Tags: r, csv, input, shiny

I have a simple question:
I have a small shiny tool which checks some rules within a csv-File.
When writing the code I tested it with a specific csv.
But if users shall use the shiny tool to verify their csv-files, the code must check the rules for the file which is uploaded in the shiny tool:

How can I store the input-file as a variable in the global Environment, so that the code is applied individually to the Input file?

My code Looks like this:

```
rm(list=ls())
source("vr_test.R")
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("xx"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("xx"),

      fileInput("file", h3("File input")),

      actionButton("button", "auswerten")

      ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("result")

    )
  )
  )


server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    output$result <- renderText({ 
    print(eval(parse(text=Formula))) # "Formula" is defined in sourced "vr_test.R"
  })
  }) 
}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store the csv in the global environment. The best practice would be to make it a `reactive`, and base your tests on that. An example is given below, that tests if a csv has sufficient rows (let's say we require more than 5 rows in this case).

Instead of a `renderText`, you could also choose to use an `observeEvent`, and show a `modalDialog` if the conditions are not met.

Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
            accept = c(
              "text/csv",
              "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
              ".csv")),
  tableOutput("contents"),
  textOutput(my_test)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Load csv as reactive
  my_csv <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    df<- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=T)
    return(df)
  })

  output$my_test <- renderText({
    validate(need(!is.null(my_csv()),'No csv uploaded.'))

    # perform test here
    if(nrow(my_csv())>5)
    {
      return('Your csv has enough rows!')
    }
    else
    {
      return('Your csv has not enough rows!')
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. For my project I need to MANIPULATE the input data - filter, extract, replace, store data as variables - to let a script (which I worked on the recent weeks) run through the input data. As result of my code there are lots of logical values after several checks (which shoud be printed in the shiny app). In general now I have to "transfer my code into the shiny-world". Can my plan be turned into reality? Thanks for further help.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly possible. I would advise you to split your plan into small steps; first just try to filter. If it works, go on to extracting. If not, ask that as a separate question on Stack Overflow. And continue like that. Good luck ;)